# Local variable pointer overwritten on each method call

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am currently reading a book on data structures and learning c++ on the side. I am trying to implement a simple linked list. Below is some code for a list that can take a maximum of two elements (in order to isolate my problem).
What is going wrong is the pointer declaration to the next node in the list. When I create a new `Node` instance and create a pointer to it, the pointer stays the same on each method call, so all elements in the list point to the same node. However, if I create a pointer directly, everything works as expected.

What I am guessing is that I have some fundamental misunderstanding of pointers, references and the `new` keyword.

Feel free to run the code below. The working code is commented out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Node {
public:
    Node(T nvalue) {
        this->value = nvalue;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    T value;
    Node *next;
};

template <typename T> class LinkedList {
    public:
        Node<T> *head;
        LinkedList() {
            this->head = NULL;
        }
        void append(T newVal) {
            // Correct
            // Node<T>* newNode_ptr = new Node<T>(newVal); // newNode_ptr is different on each call
            // Incorrect!?
            Node<T> newNode = Node<T>(newVal);
            Node<T> * newNode_ptr = &newNode; // newNode_ptr is the same on each call
            cout << "New Node Address: " << newNode_ptr << endl; 
            if (!(this->head)) {
                this->head = newNode_ptr;
                cout << "Value 0: " << this->head->value << endl;
            } else {
                this->head->next = newNode_ptr;
                cout << "Value 0: " << this->head->value << endl;
                cout << "Value 1: " << this->head->next->value << endl;
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();
    list.append(21);
    cout << "..." << endl;
    list.append(42);
}
```

Note that this code is not exactly well designed (some stuff should be private, `using namespace std` should be avoided). I am familiar with python so this pointer stuff is a little overwhelming. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: ***Node<T> * newNode_ptr = &newNode;*** Will be undefined behavior when `newNode` goes out of scope.

Comment: @drescherjm they go out of scope together so I don't see a problem

Comment: A little advice - when creating a data structure, first create it for a specific type or types. Only when you have got that working and tested, turn it into a template.

Comment: @user ***I don't see a problem*** The pointer to `newNode` is being added to a list for future use. Once `newNode` goes out of scope the pointer that points to it will no longer be valid.

Comment: @drescherjm Indeed, overlooked that part

Comment: @drescherjm So if I create and object and it moves out of scope, I can no longer use its pointer, but If i initialise a pointer, everything works as expected?

Comment: @Nico That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Node<T>* newNode_ptr = new Node<T>(newVal);
```

This is the more correct way of the two. It is normal that the address of `newNde_ptr` is different, it's what you want. Each node is a different node, two different objects cannot have the same address! The version without `new` gives the same address because you are creating the objects *on the stack*. This will not work, every node is destroyed at the end of the `append` function. You will see unusual results (if it doesn't crash) if you move the printing portion of `append` to another function. Since all your pointers point to the same address (in your case) and at the point where you print out the values that address *just so happens* to be a valid Node, you do not see a crash. However, this is undefined behavior and can change for any number of reasons.

The difference between free-store (heap for malloc/free) and the stack is a fundamental concept of c++. You should read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).

The reason I saw *more correct way of the two* is that you still have to remember to `delete` your nodes. A better way would be to use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers to avoid that (and may other) mistakes that using raw pointers encourages.

```
// Node * next; becomes
std::unique_ptr<Node> next;

// Node<T> newNode = Node<T>(newVal); becomes
newNode = std::make_unique<T>(newVal);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know it's the correct way, I was just wondering why the other solution didn't work. Could you correct my second solution where i first initialise a `Node` object and then get the associated pointer?

Comment: @Nico No, that solution cannot be made to work. You will have to do some sort of memory allocation. If an object is created on the stack, it cannot be made to survive the end of it's scope. The nearest solution would be to move it to another instance ([see move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)). This won't work in your case. It would imply that the type `Node` contains another `Node` and a value. This would then imply that `sizeof(Node) = sizeof(Node) + sizeof(T)`.